# Initial text doesn't appear in Facebook sharing in iOS 8.0.2 version device of IPAD AIR

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I tried to share the static text by using facebook sharing in my app but can't do it. Initial text doesn't appear in facebook sharing in ios 8.0.2 version device of IPAD AIR through SLComposeViewController

Answer (score 0):

Facebook no longer allows developers to set an initial text as it's violating their policy. It's now enforced.